# Plot with geom_smooth(,) multiple colours, double y-axis with four variables in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I have an issue with ggplot2 plotting system with R.

I would like to print a graph, scatterplot + smoothing with two grades (`ref`) and two variable each (`Vix`, `monomer`),  with vix referring to the left y-Axis and monomer referring to the right y-Axis. I would like to have red and blue dark colour for `ref` at 130°C and the same but pale colours for the 150°C one. Colours are the followings, but for understanding it is not really important:'#644196', '#bba6d9', '#f92410', '#fca49c'. In this way I would obtain 4 lines with 4 different colours.

I used to define the colours according the command:
scale_color_manual(values=c('#644196', '#bba6d9', '#f92410', '#fca49c')) +

The problem is that I obtain 4 lines but only two colours and also the legend has only two assignments (and not 4 as i expected). It looks like it changes the colours over the `ref` and it doesn't assign any colour change to the two variables `Vix` and `monomer`.

Below I report the whole code.

```
Dati <- data.frame("Vix" = c(62500, 87000, 122000, 140000, 82700, 73000, 110000, 110000, 140300, 81500), "monomer" = c(0.089,0.08,0.095,0.1,0.111, 0.09, 0.094, 0.099, 0.111, 0.197), "Time" = c(30, 60, 90, 120, 135, 30, 60, 90, 120, 135), "ref" = c('130°C', '130°C', '130°C', '130°C', '130°C', '150°C', '150°C', '150°C', '150°C', '150°C'))
attach(Dati)
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)


####Graph processing

scaleFactor <- max(Vix) / max(monomer)
Graph <- ggplot(Dati, aes(x= Time, col=(ref))) +


geom_point(aes(y= Vix, col=(ref)), shape = 1, size = 3.5) +
geom_smooth(aes(y= Vix), method="loess") +  


geom_point(aes(y= monomer * scaleFactor, col=ref), shape = 1, size = 3.5) + 
geom_smooth(aes(y=monomer * scaleFactor), method="loess") +  

scale_color_manual(values=c('#644196', '#bba6d9', '#f92410', '#fca49c')) +

  scale_y_continuous(name="Vix", sec.axis=sec_axis(~./scaleFactor, name="monomer")) +
  theme(
    axis.title.y.left=element_text(color='#f92410'),
    axis.text.y.left=element_text(color='#f92410'),
    axis.title.y.right=element_text(color='#644196'),
    axis.text.y.right=element_text(color='#644196')
  ) 

Graph
```

[Obtained output graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/094ZO.jpg)

Is somebody able to understand wht could I do in order to fix this issue?

Thank you in advance for every your possible kind reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to add information to the variable at the specification of aesthetics. In the example below, we `paste0()` the extra information whether the series is `Vix` or `monomer` to the colours.

```r
Graph <- ggplot(Dati, aes(x= Time)) +
  geom_point(aes(y= Vix, col=paste0("Vix ", ref)), shape = 1, size = 3.5) +
  geom_smooth(aes(y= Vix, col = paste0("Vix ", ref)), method="loess") +  
  geom_point(aes(y= monomer * scaleFactor, col=paste0("Monomer ", ref)), shape = 1, size = 3.5) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(y=monomer * scaleFactor, col = paste0("Monomer ", ref)), method="loess") +  
  scale_color_manual(values=c('#644196', '#bba6d9', '#f92410', '#fca49c'),
                     name = "Series?") +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Vix", sec.axis=sec_axis(~./scaleFactor, name="monomer")) +
  theme(
    axis.title.y.left=element_text(color='#f92410'),
    axis.text.y.left=element_text(color='#f92410'),
    axis.title.y.right=element_text(color='#644196'),
    axis.text.y.right=element_text(color='#644196')
  ) 

Graph
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot, everybody, for your helpfulness! Only one question fot @det. When I paste the first part of your code, defining the datased `Dati`, at the last line I get an error: `Error in Dati %>% mutate(monomer = monomer * scaleFactor) %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(Vix,  : 
  not able to find the function "%>%"`  Is pherap any library to be used? @teunbrand, it works fine. I will investigate more on the function paste0() which can be useful in these cases.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 colors because your variable mapped to color (`ref`) has 2 distinct values. I guess you would like to have `Vix` and `monomer` curves for each value of `ref`. You can get that by getting your data into long format and creating new variable that refers to temperature and to Vix or monomer:

```
scaleFactor <- max(Dati$Vix) / max(Dati$monomer)
```

**STEP 1**: calculate `monomer`, create column that tells you if value if Vix or monomer (long format for those two variables), and recreate `ref`

```
Dati <- Dati %>%
  mutate(
    monomer = monomer * scaleFactor
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(Vix, monomer)) %>%
  mutate(ref = str_c(ref, name, sep = "-"))
```

**STEP 2** map `ref` to color aesthetic (long format is neat for `ggplot2`)

```
ggplot(Dati, aes(Time, value, color = ordered(ref, levels = unique(ref)))) +
  geom_point(shape = 1, size = 3.5) +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess") +
  scale_color_manual("groups", values = c('#fca49c', '#bba6d9', '#f92410', '#644196')) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Vix", sec.axis = sec_axis(~./scaleFactor, name = "monomer")) +
  theme(
    axis.title.y.left = element_text(color = '#f92410'),
    axis.text.y.left = element_text(color = '#f92410'),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = '#644196'),
    axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = '#644196')
  )
```

**RESULT**:

[image]

Comment: @GiacomoDB yes you need `library(dplyr)` and `library(tidyr)`

Comment: Thank you det for your help!

Comment: It works fine also. It needs also `library(stringr)`